# Compute bill for a super market

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, python-2.4

Below is the code to compute the bill for the supermarket.  Everything is ok but the issue is that I am told that this solution would not work if the input is only apple.

I do believe that the value of apple should be 0 since apples are not in the stock but still I believe there is something that I am not doing correct.  Please help.

```
groceries = ["apple","banana", "orange",]

stock = {"banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
    }

prices = {"banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
    }

def computeBill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        tot = prices[item] * stock[item]
        print item, tot
        total += tot
    return total

computeBill(groceries)
```

Comment: What would you like the logic to do if the item is not in stock? It's not really a problem with this code..its just...what do you want it to do?

Comment: What did the person say should happen if the input is `["apple"]`?

Comment: Also, the way you have the code set up in `computeBill`, it will bill them for then entire stock of the item. Is that what you want? And if I put "banana" multiple times, I get double the available stock.

Comment: I really do not care about that case.  The only issue is that this solution would not work for input when groceries contains just 'apple'

Comment: Well...yes it does still "work". You get `0`. What 'should' it do? A `None`? An exception? Print something?

Comment: This is the text that I get 
`You code doesn't seem to work when ['apple'] is used as input.`

Comment: That text is poor direction. "Doesn't seem to work" is not constructive. It's obviously not your own fault. You apparently are not told what to do if all requested items are out of stock.

Comment: Any constructive changes that I should look at?  May be that would fix the issue?

Comment: Is there an automated checker giving you that text? (In any case you should ask the instructor).

Comment: Maybe you could include what purpose this program should fulfill? Should it include all items in stock from a type if it is included in `groceries`?

Comment: I'm not sure how much I trust the Python compiler on Codeacademy. I've accidently clicked run a few times when I am halfway through the coding process and the compiler congratulates me and tells me to move on to the next exercise. Being new to Python, I then take the code to test it in PyScripter and it wont work. I have doubts about the behind the scenes code of this compiler, so I always check it in PyScripter (which I know for sure works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to go off on my own with this answer and make suggestions, since it seems the specifications for your `computeBill` functionality are not well defined.

If the items are not in stock, and your instructor says it is not acceptable to return `0` in this case, then your other options are to raise an exception, or a sentinel value indicating an error state.

```
def computeBill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        stock_count = stock[item]
        if stock_count == 0:
            raise ValueError("item %s is out of stock" % item)
        tot = prices[item] * stock_count
        print item, tot
        total += tot
    return total
```

Or if you don't want to raise an exception, you could return `-1` if you feel that is not a valid total anyways:

```
        if stock_count == 0:
            return -1
```

There are some other problems with the function in how it calculates the list vs stock, but you said you didn't care about those right now.

Comment: I am guessing that the stock_count is what was needed.  Because everything else is the same.  Thanks.

Comment: The `stock_count` is just saving `stock[item]` ahead of time in a variable, so that I don't have to type it twice for the `if` and the `*`. It doesn't change much. This actually changes the behavior of the function by raising an exception or returning a -1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this wouldn't work. If your input was `['apple']`, this would happen:

```
computeBill(['apple'])
total = 0
item = 'apple'
tot = price['apple'] * stock['apple']
tot = 2 * 0
print 'apple',0
total += 0
return total
return 0
```

Unless they expect to be able to pass in a single item without wrapping it in a list, so calling `computeBill('apple'). In that case, you'd have to do a type check at the beginning of your function. That could look like this

```
if type(food) is not list:
    food = [food]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_bill(food):
  total=0
  for item in food:
    if stock[item]>0:
      tot=prices[item]
      total+=tot
      stock[item]-=1
  return total
```